# Is git push just slow or is there something wrong?

Tags: git, github, push

I had lots related code scattered around which I decided to consolidate into one github repo. I accidentally commited, pushed, moved and removed larger files (greater than 50MB). I'm not very experienced with git and so did lots of things like using mv/rm instead of git mv/rm. I retrospectively tried to correct this but am not sure if I've just confused things.

Since doing all that when I try to push I just get:

```
-bash-4.1$ git push
Counting objects: 1288, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
compressing objects:  87% (1060/1211)
```

But it just seems to hang there. Is there a way to tell if there's a problem or if I just need to wait longer?

I tried to increase the post buffer with:

```
-bash-4.1$ git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

but this didn't seem to help.

To give you and idea of the repo/file sizes I did:

```
-bash-4.1$ du -sh *
126M    mg
4.0K    readme.md

-bash-4.1$ find ./ -type f -size +50M -exec ls -lh {} \;
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 55M Oct 25 18:48 ./.git/objects/a6/c86199d33fac72d856d3381fe07239d7089b80
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 65M Oct 25 19:00 ./.git/objects/d6/c82684b7db5939dbec6193d9a16b9b0954740c
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 56M Oct 25 18:57 ./.git/objects/bd/0a85627a6fe53e0322ebf33c70d1ad1f26642b
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 67M Oct 25 18:56 ./.git/objects/63/4209365d534cc6dd7d081c949b123df8052bd0
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 60M Oct 25 18:55 ./.git/objects/2b/25a30d92e48a72e32d7062a4c5ffc5734fec94
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 58M Oct 25 18:46 ./.git/objects/50/5495be51d3d8bd98b0c67a3ed41859fc92153f
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 58M Oct 25 19:03 ./.git/objects/38/99700d5472df9442e118c82dd8fe9ee336bc5b
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 52M Oct 25 18:44 ./.git/objects/b4/42ac818898e285c524e9300ecfa46ca53a2c3c
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 54M Oct 25 19:00 ./.git/objects/4f/386fbc1389074f548a70a7a6f6e65df1a57710
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 53M Oct 25 18:55 ./.git/objects/37/c25b249642f200c8e5c427d1c6d9b57c5ed089
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 51M Oct 25 18:37 ./.git/objects/e9/54a09381e8e9a452a672886536718f73587e31
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 52M Oct 25 18:37 ./.git/objects/b2/3ab90e379e2647c0bb9ccfdc6346b2c3d8df8f
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 57M Oct 25 18:59 ./.git/objects/ac/ca72cfb9a4537828fd747b0a05ec0a79efdc65
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 55M Oct 25 18:47 ./.git/objects/2e/da077ed31886e677dcb2b4bc6b1abe340527b6
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 56M Oct 25 18:41 ./.git/objects/2e/d7ea9d06803d85ce9504c69619c516c2bac928
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 51M Oct 25 18:45 ./.git/objects/04/b1e3fdcf9bc74c696f77c3b7d5f0d2fa5be992
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 59M Oct 25 18:57 ./.git/objects/d5/355a991c4812379649e94123feb518160cc6cb
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 53M Oct 25 18:56 ./.git/objects/ec/93271bb4b898438b2c90b7048a26f8dc54b553
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 63M Oct 25 18:47 ./.git/objects/85/e33df7c1882788b12ee866d8c38427bd22aa44
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 55M Oct 25 18:48 ./.git/objects/ce/70d6d87e7d810c570da3e2e534213653c05de6
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 57M Oct 25 18:37 ./.git/objects/7a/abe86d346247dceadb0324696a044331f56440
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 51M Oct 25 18:46 ./.git/objects/2a/d85020500a36387d60046c9e5ddf500aa44286
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 59M Oct 25 18:59 ./.git/objects/fb/6928f2f569361935db50d4f0ed8ece5feaf6f1
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 54M Oct 25 19:01 ./.git/objects/c6/c2843b3b40bf6c6b7b6f974f004009b8e45e4e
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 56M Oct 25 18:47 ./.git/objects/fe/0b521c082fb0290bb011c73daba372b4805db4
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 61M Oct 25 19:02 ./.git/objects/5a/373c53b589d429eff09e1d2a18d9b7f85658cf
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 53M Oct 25 18:37 ./.git/objects/bb/e662205d31a9ccbd2d755fc46f99aae4bd0fe2
-r--r--r-- 1 oc13378 emat13r 51M Oct 25 18:37 ./.git/objects/69/32e59d33eae1e13357d0e048dee3f77b97ba72
```

One last things is that the computer is old and doesn't have much RAM. Could this be a problem?

```
-bash-4.1$ free
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8059876    1112512    6947364          0       6372     927848
-/+ buffers/cache:     178292    7881584
Swap:      4194300      31156    4163144
-bash-4.1$ free -m
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7870       1086       6784          0          6        906
-/+ buffers/cache:        174       7696
Swap:         4095         30       4065
```

My most recent try ended in failure:

```
-bash-4.1$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
-bash-4.1$ git push
Counting objects: 1288, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: pack-objects died of signal 9)   
error: pack-objects died with strange error
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git-uni:OliCUoB/wc.git'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One last things is that the computer is old and doesn't have much RAM. Could this be a problem?

Yes.  The `signal 9` means your pack process (building a thin pack to send off to GitHub) has been killed by the "OOM killer".  See also [Git out of memory and then fatal - early EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28156058/1256452) (which is a case where the *server* ran out of memory, hence a bit different).

You can try fussing with the packing parameters on your side:

- `core.packedGitWindowSize`
- `core.packedGitLimit`
- `pack.window`
- `pack.depth`
- `pack.windowMemory`
- `pack.deltaCacheSize`
- `pack.threads` (not specifically memory related, but more threads = more RAM needed)

but your best bet is to give your machine more memory (real RAM, swap / paging space, or both).

Answer (score 2):

This solved for me

`git reset origin/branchName`

`git add -a`, `git commit -m "commit message"`

`git push`

Answer (score 2):

One additional setting can help speed up a `git push`:

```
git -c push.useBitmaps=false push
```

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), "[`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/81705c4ee657b55900c35ef38d0641d9ce2d0092/Documentation/git-push.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> sometimes perform poorly when reachability bitmaps are used, even in a repository where other operations are helped by bitmaps.
The `push.useBitmaps` configuration variable is introduced to allow disabling use of reachability bitmaps only for `git push`.

See [commit 82f67ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82f67ee13fb25ebed1cd722c83de49a1ac588429) (17 Jun 2022) by [Kyle Zhao (`yefengzkk`)](https://github.com/yefengzkk).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 81705c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81705c4ee657b55900c35ef38d0641d9ce2d0092), 13 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`send-pack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82f67ee13fb25ebed1cd722c83de49a1ac588429): add config push.useBitmaps
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kyle Zhao</sup>

> Reachability bitmaps are designed to speed up the "counting objects" phase of generating a pack during a clone or fetch.
> They are not optimized for Git clients sending a small topic branch via `git push`.
> In some cases (see [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/87zhoz8b9o.fsf@evledraar.gmail.com/), using reachability bitmaps during "[`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/82f67ee13fb25ebed1cd722c83de49a1ac588429/Documentation/git-push.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> can cause significant performance regressions.
>
> Add a new "`push.useBitmaps`" configuration variable to allow users to tell "`git push`" not to use bitmaps.
> We already have "`pack.bitmaps`" that controls the use of bitmaps, but a separate configuration variable allows the reachability bitmaps to still be used in other areas, such as "[`git upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/82f67ee13fb25ebed1cd722c83de49a1ac588429/Documentation/git-upload-pack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack))</sup>, while disabling it only for `git push`".

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/82f67ee13fb25ebed1cd722c83de49a1ac588429/Documentation/config/push.txt#L140-L144):

> ### `push.useBitmaps`
>
> If set to "false", disable use of bitmaps for "`git push`" even if
> `pack.useBitmaps` is "true", without preventing other git operations
> from using bitmaps.
> Default is true.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced some unexpected slowness for each operation in git. Then I use

> git prune