# Git warning: "Disabling bitmap writing"

Tags: git, bitbucket

Performing a `git push` is returning the following messages after successfully sending changes to the remote.

```
error: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
and remove gc.log.
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

warning: disabling bitmap writing, as some objects are not being packed
```

Usually when the garbage collector returns warnings a `git prune` fixes it.  Both that and `git gc --aggressive` haven't fixed this issue and don't return any errors or warnings.  The file `.git/gc.log` doesn't exist.

This is a very large repo hosted on a private Bitbucket server.

What does "disabling bitmap writing, as some objects are not being packed" mean and how do we fix it?  Where is the gc.log file?

Comment: I've seen gc.log before, that's located in the .git directory of the repo. I've never seen the bitmap warning before though. (Also, hi Matt. :)

Comment: Hey, Michael!  I can't see any gc.log in the .git or .git/logs directory. Even `find . -iname gc.log` returns nothing.

Comment: Is the gc.log on the remote server?

Comment: @o11c No. I did once see it locally in another situation, but never when this warning comes up.

Comment: Note: See also with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) the new setting [`git -c push.useBitmaps=false push`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73012939/6309), to disable packing for `git push`. No more warning in that case.

Answer (score 3):

The `gc.log` file is left behind by a `git gc --auto` when it wants to report something (anything, at all, the problem being that `git gc --auto` was spun off in the background and has nowhere to report to, other than this log file).

As for the warning itself: bitmaps are used to speed up object traversal (i.e., to optimize server performance).  This only works if all the objects are actually in the pack, which is what that warning means.

It's not clear to me why some objects are not being packed.  The message comes from `add_object_entry` in `builtin/pack-objects.c`, if we don't want to put this object into the pack as determined by function `want_object_in_pack` in the same file.  That in turn depends on `--local` and whether there are `.keep` files maintaining previous packs.

Git versions 2.12.2 and 2.13.0 added a hack to ignore (and remove) stale `gc.log` files, since their presence disables further `git gc --auto` operations.  If your Git is this new, it will remove those stale files when the log expires, which defaults to 24 hours (`1.day`).  See the `gc.logExpire` description in [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

Comment: This is very informative.  I am on 2.13.3.  If I run just `git gc` I see no warning or log file.  Only when I pull down new changes.  The log file is never there even if I set `gc.logExpire` explicitly to `1.day`.

Comment: A regular (not `--auto`) `git gc` has somewhere to report to, so it won't write a log file even if it complains. The trick would be to get a non-auto gc to occur when you can spot it, or catch the auto-gc failure very quickly. I suspect there's something else going on with alternate object stores or some such, but don't know what.